# Excel LEFT and RIGHT Formulas Incorrectly Splitting Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do something very basic--take a list of emails and web urls in one column, and split them into a column for emails, and the other for the urls.

To accomplish this, I have tried the following formulas:

```
=LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ",A2,1))
```

And

```
=RIGHT(A2, SEARCH("  ",A2,1))
```

Should the format of the first column be [Email] [URL] it SHOULD split this so the the column with the first function receives the emails, whereas the second would receive the URL's.

However, this is not the case. Instead, I get something ugly, like this:
[image]

As you can see, in the first cell, it works perfectly fine. However, in the lower cells you can clearly see things break. Values overlap, like in row 6 column 3... why? There are clearly no additional spaces besides those between the email and url in the first column.

Comment: Do you need to use a formula? You could just do Data-->Text to Columns with a comma delimiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SEARCH("  ",A2,1)` finds the first space location from the ***LEFT***.

So it is passing that number to the `RIGHT()` Function which expects the number of characters wanted from the ***RIGHT*** not the ***LEFT***.

Use:

```
=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2) - SEARCH("  ",A2,1))
```

Answer (score 3):

The search returns the length of the email, so in your formula you are taking the right-most quantity equal to the length of the email and not the website.  You need to use:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the **http://** on each line, which is what your statement ***As you can see, in the first cell, it works perfectly fine***, you can use

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("/",A2,1)-1)
```